# Turbulence from a sphere spinning in an incompressible liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, turbulence, vortex

When I look online I can find plenty of simulations of Stokes flow: incompressible liquid flowing past a spherical object. What I'm interested in is the problem of a sphere (of given size) spinning (with given angular velocity) in an incompressible liquid (of given density and viscosity). This is quite related, as here too we define characteristic length and velocity scales, and therefore I expect there to be a laminar–turbulent transition to happen at some range of values for the Reynolds number. What point do we observe turbulence to set in, and what does this look like? Can I find simulations of this scenario somewhere? Both the 2D and 3D case are appreciated.

Comment: Try extending your searches to include air at low Mach numbers - not just liquids. There should be plenty of studies involving baseballs, golf balls, etc.

Comment: @D.Halsey Good point, will do!